# How do I find out what version of a bower package is actually installed?

Tags: json, bower, versioning, semantic-versioning

Normally a `bower.json` file specifies some dependencies, but these are typically expressed so that they allow a range of versions of a bower package to be used (e.g. `>=1.0`, which means anything higher than version 1.0).

I have an automated process which needs to find what version of a bower package is *actually installed* on this system right now.

How can I find this out programmatically (just the version itself), ideally using standard Unix command line tools / the bower command?

`bower info <thepackagename>` does *not* show this - it shows information about what is currently available from the bower repository (for example, even if I do `bower info apackageIdonthaveinstalled` it will still show a valid JSON structure containing a version number).

`cat bower_components/thepackagename/bower.json | node_modules/json/lib/json.js version` works for some packages (assuming the npm package `json` is installed), but not all (e.g. jquery 2.2.0's bower package does not contain a bower.json).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best approach I've now found, which seems to work for every package I've come across so far, is:

`cat bower_components/thepackagename/.bower.json | node_modules/json/lib/json.js version`

(note the extra `.` in `.bower.json`).

It would appear that bower stores some metadata about the installed package in `.bower.json`, and that includes the installed version.

<strike>The best I've come up with so far is:</strike>

```
bower list | grep jquery | perl -pe 's/.*jquery#(.*?) .*$/$1/'
```

(if, for example, the package I was interested in was `jquery`).

That's pretty ugly for a variety of reasons:

- I have to repeat the package name (although this could probably be improved
  with a better Perl script which filters lines too, I'm just being lazy).
- `bower list` gets information about all installed packages, not just the one I'm interested in - the rest of the information is discarded.
- `bower list` seems to require internet connectivity to check the registry, otherwise it fails.

Would be interested to see if this could be improved upon, particularly the last point.

Answer (score 29):

Here's a grep command to do that:

`grep "version\"\:" bower_components/thepackagename/.bower.json`

Also, a command to see versions of all bower components for the project - this list can be a handy CI artefact:

`grep "version\"\:" bower_components/*/.bower.json`

[image]

Comment: As noted in the question, this doesn't work for packages that don't contain a `bower.json`.

Comment: Note the extra . in .bower.json ;)

So this command is essentially the same as you use, except that it doesn't depend on `json` package, and it shows versions of *all* bower dependencies for current package.

Comment: Understood, but it's not really the question I was asking. I was asking for one specific version for one specific package. This lists them all. But you're right, it does have the advantage of not depending on the `json` package. I'll upvote, but I'm leaving mine as the accepted answer since it's the closest to the question.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier thank you, just in case I'll edit my answer then to match your Q

Comment: @AndrewFerrier It does work if a tag is checked out. E.g. [`"https://github.com/msieurtoph/angular-checkboxes.git#1.0.2"`](https://github.com/msieurtoph/angular-checkboxes/tree/1.0.2) has no `bower.json`, but the resulting `.bower.json` contains `"version": "1.0.2"`. If you don't specify a tag _then_ no version is available, but `_resolution.commit` might be defined instead.

Answer (score 8):

Have you ever tried "bower list --json=0 --offline".

It would list all bower packages info.